# How is the DI relative to constructor and/or property injection solved in Kephas?

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac, kephas

I noticed that most DI frameworks use the constructor approach, but some support also setting dependencies through properties. How does Kephas regard this problem and what built-in means are provided for that? Disclaimer: I think about supporting Autofac, but this depends on my spare time. I saw that something was started in this direction in Kephas, but this seems at the very beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, Kephas is dependent on which DI container you choose. If you are talking about Autofac (as well as MEF/System.Composition), it supports both constructor and property injection. All Kephas service implementation use exclusively the constructor injection, with the notable exception of the `Logger` property. This is by design, as to inject it through constructor seemed not very nice.